# How to Enter Text in the Text Field using Sense Talk and Eggplant?

Tags: automation, eggplant

I need to enter the user name on the username field. I used the below code. But TypeText is not enter the text on the Username Field

Click "TxtField_Username"
TypeText "xx@gmail.com"

Please let me know anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

- First you have to take the image of text field
- but make sure the hotspot should be in textbox
- then you can use the command TypeText abc@gmail.com - dont use semicolns while you using TypeText command.

Comment: Thanks Vital.. I found this earlier but forgot to post the answers.. thanks for answers..

Answer (score 0):

tap"loginusernameField"

```
TypeText backspace
TypeText customerUsername
TypeText Tab
TypeText deleteKey
TypeText customerPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the correct hotspot will resolve the issue, else use Imagelocation(Text) to find the label and using coordinates reach the text box. This will be dynamic.